# Is teleporting out of a grab considered escaping it?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation, grapple, immediate-interrupt

I had a game the other night, and the guys ran into a few hellstinger scorpions. One of them grabbed the assassin, and when it was his turn he teleported out of the grab.

The scorpion has an attack power, "Reactive Sting", which allows it to use it's sting attack against an enemy as an immediate interrupt, the trigger being when the target escapes its grab. I saw that the Escape action in the handbook is a move action itself, so I made the call that the scorpion did not get it's reactive sting due to the fact that he escaped with a teleport (he teleported out of it's reach of course).

So I'm just curious, did I make the right call on that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Teleporting away is a method of escaping. Though it is not taking the escape action.

> A grabbed creature can take the escape action to try to get away. Other common tactics for *escaping a grab* are to teleport away or to be pulled, pushed, or slid out of the grabber’s reach. Using forced movement on the grabber can also end a grab, as long as the movement results in the grabbed creature being out of the grabbing effect’s range. (RC 231, emphasis mine)

The power in question does not specify the method just the result. Thus the sting should have triggered, and been resolved *before* the teleport.

> Reactive Sting (immediate interrupt, when an enemy grabbed by the scorpion escapes, at-will)
>
> The hellstinger scorpion makes a hellish sting attack against the enemy.

Were this attack an opportunity action, it would not be triggered because teleporting does not trigger opportunity actions related to movement.

Answer (score -5):

The description of immediate interrupt states:

> Interruption means the triggered action happens before the trigger, and if the trigger becomes impossible to complete, it is lost. For example, if a monster uses a standard action to make a ranged attack, but an opportunity attack interrupts the monster's attack and drops the monster's hit points to 0, the monster's attack is canceled and its standard action is lost.

and

> A character may take one immediate action per round, during another combatant's turn. An immediate interrupt interrupts the action that triggers it.

So yes, the attack should have triggered.

From a storytelling perspective, you could phrase it as "As your mind focuses on teleporting, you feel a searing pain as the scorpion hits you with a sting."

Comment: This is an immediate interrupt, it's not an opportunity attack. if it was an opportunity action, it would not be triggered by a teleport. However, since it's an interrupt, the teleport triggers it, and then it happens *before* the teleport does (interrupt).

Comment: @waxeagle Been a long time since I played.  Does this mean the scorpion has some way of knowing/sensing you are about to attempt an escape and so the attack goes off preemptively?

Comment: given that it happens literally *before* you escape, yes, it would have to. In the same way a fighter can beat on you before you escape. It's worth noting though that usually the ingame explanation is left to the players/DM. 4e has a very right adherence to the RAW so statements like "this is a case where commonsense overrides the rulebook" don't really compute in the system.

Comment: @Kevin Has it been a long time since you played D&D *4e* specifically? Or just D&D in general? (If the latter: 4e is way, way different than what you're used to and you should be cautious about answering rules questions about it, possibly avoiding doing so altogether.)

Comment: The latter. I will be careful about answering questions from now on.  I still think that there are situations where you have to take into account the story and what is happening, not just blindly follow the rules no what.  Unless it is so radically different from what I am used to that it has stopped being a role playing game and is now a straight up board game,

Comment: @Kevin It turns out that you *can* just follow the rules, and still roleplay. One of the nice things about 4e is that the books themselves are relatively light when it comes to *how* or *why* things happen the way they do, and you’re encouraged to answer those questions any way that makes sense in the story. It’s also relatively light on non-combat rules, leaving plenty of room for roleplaying. But you *can* also let the narrative override the rulebook; it’s just that 4e asks you to do so with care. I think this is perhaps just not a situation where other 4e players agree it’s a good idea.

Comment: (I have unfortunately played too little of 4e to judge your suggestion myself)

Comment: @waxeagle, I'll admit my answer was not a good one. But if it happens _before_ you escape, then the name _Reactive_ Sting, as well as the description are poorly chosen.

Comment: @KRyan Yes, it's not a good idea because it quite seriously undermines the power of immediate interrupts.

Comment: @waxeagle Did some research.  The description of immediate interrupt states "A character may take one immediate action per round, during another combatant's turn. An immediate interrupt interrupts the action that triggers it. An immediate reaction occurs after the action that triggers it. If the trigger is movement, an immediate reaction may occur **after** the first space of movement, interrupting the rest of the movement, if any." If that is the case, then the escapee would be out of range and the sting might fire, but would surely miss.  Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Immediate **interrupt** and immediate **reaction** are two separate things in 4e. Note that the rules you've quoted say "An **immediate interrupt** interrupts the action that triggers it. An **immediate reaction** occurs after the action that triggers it. If the trigger is movement, an **immediate reaction** may occur after..."

Comment: @PurpleMonkey I got ya. I was reading it like they were two different names for the same thing.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this was gonna get so in depth, I suppose it's a sticky subject but what waxeagle said makes sense, it does not specify the method only the result. Had the trigger said 'the target uses an escape action to escape the grab' then my call would apply. That being said..... my group of cretins will soon be resting in the desert.... mm hmm, I guess next game some scorpions are gonna roll up on their camp...... heheheheheheh.......

Comment: Regarding the last edit: keeping it around because it has good discussion attached to it isn't helpful, because comments are temporary, so the discussion won't be here later. If you want to preserve the discussion's informational value, you should synthesise it into a proper answer instead. If you're not interested in reworking the answer to present these insights in a cohesive post, deleting is probably for the best.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie will do.